# rails POST on /objects calling index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

Normally in rails, sending a POST to a RESTful controller, say, `/orders`, calls the `#create` action. This is what I want to happen. Instead, the `#index` method gets called. How do I fix this?

The server log from a POST to `/orders`:

```
Started POST "/orders" for 173.8.132.62 at 2013-03-24 14:45:23 -0700
Processing by OrdersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EcsAZxbyd5OVVo5oIJZM/CNoyP7Cz6dRVBU7I41xENY=", "order"=>{"order_lines_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"item_id"=>"", "qty"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "customer_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Order"}
  Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

The entire `routes.rb`:

```
Wines::Application.routes.draw do

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
        resources :customers do
                resources :phones
                resources :addresses
        end

        resources :distributors do
                resources :distributor_phones
                resources :distributor_addresses
        end

        resources :items do
                post 'sample', :on => :member
        end

        resources :orders do
                post 'place', :on => :member
                post 'deliver', :on => :member
                resources :order_lines
        end

        resources :db do
                post 'query', :on => :collection
        end


        resources :images, :beverage_types, :grapes


end
```

Some possibly relevant lines routes from `rake routes`:

```
                     place_order POST   /orders/:id/place(.:format)                                            orders#place
                   deliver_order POST   /orders/:id/deliver(.:format)                                          orders#deliver
               order_order_lines GET    /orders/:order_id/order_lines(.:format)                                order_lines#index
                                 POST   /orders/:order_id/order_lines(.:format)                                order_lines#create
            new_order_order_line GET    /orders/:order_id/order_lines/new(.:format)                            order_lines#new
           edit_order_order_line GET    /orders/:order_id/order_lines/:id/edit(.:format)                       order_lines#edit
                order_order_line GET    /orders/:order_id/order_lines/:id(.:format)                            order_lines#show
                                 PUT    /orders/:order_id/order_lines/:id(.:format)                            order_lines#update
                                 DELETE /orders/:order_id/order_lines/:id(.:format)                            order_lines#destroy
                          orders GET    /orders(.:format)                                                      orders#index
                                 POST   /orders(.:format)                                                      orders#create
                       new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                                                  orders#new
                      edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                             orders#edit
                           order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                                                  orders#show
                                 PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                                                  orders#update
                                 DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                                                  orders#destroy
```

I'm using formtastic, and my _form.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.semantic_fields_for :order_lines do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'order_line_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Order Line", f, :order_lines %>
  <%= f.inputs :customer %>
  <%= f.actions %>

<% end %>
```

The generated html `<form>` tag looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/orders" class="formtastic order" id="new_order" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
```

The generated submit action looks like this:

```
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Order" />
```

Relevant code from the controller is as follows. When I submit a POST to `/orders`, I get

> this is the index method, called with URL `http://w:3000/orders` and
>   method POST.

```
  def index
    @orders = Order.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml # index.xml.erb                                                                                                                                          
      format.html {render :text => "this is the index method, called with URL #{request.url} and method #{request.method}"}
    end
  end


  # GET /orders/1.xml                                                                                                                                                     
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render xml: @order.to_xml }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/new.xml                                                                                                                                                   
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    1.times {@order.order_lines.build}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render xml: @order.to_xml }
      format.html {}
    end
  end

  # POST /orders.xml                                                                                                                                                      
  def create

    @order = Order.new(params[:order])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.xml { render xml: @order.to_noko_doc }
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.'}
      else
        format.xml { render xml: @order.errors }
        format.html {render action: 'new'}
      end
    end
```

Comment: could you show us the form as well.

Comment: added the form, plus some generated HTML

Comment: What does your Orders controller look like?

Comment: posted the relevent section. sorry for the delay.

Comment: Is there anything else related to orders in your routes.rb?

Comment: I do not think so. But just in case, I've posted the whole routes.rb file above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'` route is getting matched first for the `POST` to `orders#create`, move it to the bottom of your routes file

Answer (score 1):

Routes are matched in the order they are defined, so if your index route `/orders` comes before your create route `/orders :via => [:post]`, the former will be invoked.  Try placing your post route first.

```
match "orders" => "orders#create", :via => [:post]
# then resources :orders
```

Comment: Thanks. I picked the other answer as the correct solution because it points out the error I made that caused this problem.